# Difference between ls -a and ls -alps

Tags: gnu, ls

[image: Sample results]

I don't understand the difference between ls -a and -alps. I can see the result is different but I'm not sure why its display is different. More specifically I don't really know -alps does. it does not show up anywhere when searching for man ls and does not show up on the web.

A follow up question is what do the text prior to the directory names signify? For example:
`4 drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Jan 11 19:18`

Thank you!

Comment: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ls+-alps

Comment: Note that `-alps` is (in this case) the same as `-a -l -p -s`.

Comment: I wish I knew that site earlier thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`ls -alps` is the same as `ls -a -l -p -s`

`-a`: All files are being presented (even if they start if a dot)

`-l`: The files are being presented in a listing format

`-p`: A slash (/) is being appended to all directories

`-s`: The size of each file is being shown